# MongoDB Fails due to permission error even though its setup

Tags: mongodb, permissions, linux, mongodb-3.4

Attempting to start my MongoDB server using `service mongod start` fails for the reason: exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongo/, terminating

I've setup the permissions to the directories it needs using chown mongod:mongod -R /var/lib/mongo/ and also ran chmod 775 -R /var/lib/mongo

Even though I can see that the group and permissions are setup for the directory /var/lib/mongo its still saying the folder is read-only?

Have I missed something in my setup? I'll attach the ls -ld output of my mongo data folder.

drwxrwxr-x. 5 mongod mongod 8192 May 29 15:35 /var/lib/mongo

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860208/not-able-to-run-mongodb-on-ubuntu/54860342#54860342

Comment: Thanks I looked into it but its not really a solution to the problem, I'm not understanding why a folder with 777 permissions (I know its bad but i want to confirm if its a folder thing or not) cannot access and create a file.

Comment: Are you logged in as a `mongod` user?